# How can I capture native view to video in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, video

How can I capture the native view to video in react native (more like screen recording only the View).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `react-native-record-screen` library that allow you to record the screen you can check it from [here](https://github.com/yutasuzuki/react-native-record-screen#readme).